# jQuery :contains help. Need it to select "8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m."

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I'm having an issue writing jQuery that will identify "8:00 p.m." appearing twice. Everything I write, that will successfully change 
"8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m." (henceforth referred to as "A") to "8:00 p.m." will also change 
"8:00 p.m. - 10:00 p.m." (henceforth referred to as "B") and 
"6:00 a.m. - 8:00 p.m." (henceforth referred to as "C") to "8:00 p.m."

The time comes from PHP, and writing a solution in PHP is beyond my brain's capacity given how complicated the PHP already is for displaying almost every possible 
"Friday, March 31, 2017 - Friday, April 14, 2017, 9:00 a.m. - 10:00 p.m." to 
"Friday, April 28, 2017, 2:00 p.m. - 4:00 p.m." to 
"Thursday, February 09, 2017 - Saturday, February 11, 2017, 8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m." and everything in between, so I'm trying to write a solution in jQuery that will fix the issue. The actual issue is created when an event has several performances over a period of days and no end time. Ex: An event starts Thursday, Friday, and Saturday at 8:00 p.m. and does not have an end time. So what ends up happening is 8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m. is displayed. I want to use jQuery to change that to simply 8:00 p.m.

The simplest solution does not work and does not change A, B, or C.

```
$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m.")').text('8:00 p.m.');
```

I assume it is because of the hyphen, but that is just a guess.

However, changing "-" to "-" in both the PHP and jQuery doesn't work. Changing it to "-" in just the PHP and leaving "-" in the jQuery doesn't work either.

Everything that DOES WORK, ends up changing A, B, and C because the code sees "8:00" appearing once and doesn't know that it is ONLY supposed to be working if it sees 2 instances of "8:00".

Below is a list of others solutions I have tried that do not specifically ONLY change A to 8:00 p.m. and NOT B and C:

```
$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00"):contains("p.m."):contains("-"):contains("8:00"):contains("p.m.")').text('8:00 p.m.');

$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00 p.m. -"):contains("8:00 p.m.")').text('8:00 p.m.');

$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00 p.m."):contains("- 8:00 p.m.")').text('8:00 p.m.');

$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00 p.m."):contains("-"):contains("8:00 p.m.")').text('8:00 p.m.');
```

I've tried others, but I've already erased them from my code. All of those above do not necessarily work at all.

The code below works for A and B, but it's cumbersome and stupid, and I'd have to write it much, much, much longer to cover every possible option, like C, and I don't like that idea.

```
$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00"):contains("p.m."):contains("-"):contains("8:00"):contains("p.m."):not(:contains("9:00"):contains("p.m.")):not(:contains("10:00"):contains("p.m."))').text('8:00 p.m.');
```

So... maybe you guys can figure this out, because I'm at my wit's end.

I am currently using what is below, but I hate it--it's stupid, even if it works. And I would have to write iterations that cover more than just 8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m.

```
$('span.eventTime:contains("8:00"):contains("p.m."):contains("-"):contains("8:00"):contains("p.m."):not(:contains("a.m.")):not(:contains("1")):not(:contains("2")):not(:contains("3")):not(:contains("4")):not(:contains("5")):not(:contains("6")):not(:contains("7")):not(:contains("9")):not(:contains("10")):not(:contains("11")):not(:contains("12"))').text('8:00 p.m.');
```

Comment: Will moment.js help you?

Comment: note: my HTML for a hyphen ended up turning into a hyphen. I had "& # 45;" without the spaces written.

Here is the corrected sentence:

However, changing "-" to "& # 45;" in both the PHP and jQuery doesn't work. Changing it to "& # 45;" in just the PHP and leaving "-" in the jQuery doesn't work either.

Comment: That's pretty cool johnny, but I am under a deadline and don't have time to implement something new.

Comment: You definitely can't change the PHP?

Comment: I could, but I don't know how to write the complicated statement to prevent 8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m. from happening.

Comment: As a suggestion, I know you want the answer, but it might be better to post the PHP instead of the JavaScript.  If it were me, I'd want to consider limiting it on the server-side.  Others may disagree.

Comment: Unfortunately it would take me so long to post ~80 lines of mixed HTML and PHP code here, properly formatted, that I would fall even further behind on my work. Someday I might be able to do that, but I really need this Band-aid jQuery approach to work right now.

Comment: [non-repro](https://jsfiddle.net/gLppnem4/) ([here it is with the entity you provided, still working.](https://jsfiddle.net/gLppnem4/1/)) you haven't proven that you actually have a solveable problem.

Comment: I see that your fiddle works Kevin, so there must be something else preventing the same solution from working for me. My hypothesis that the hyphen might be an issue is obviously false. Since the string is created by so many if/else statements, I assume the reason it doesn't work is because jQuery sees the contents of the span w/ class eventTime as not being one simple string.

Comment: i can't think of anything that would make your original not work and your "working" one work. just doesn't make sense. :contains looks at all child elements, so it can't be nesting,

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me using vanilla JS, but I wrapped in a JQ doc ready.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('eventTime');
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        var time = spans[i].innerHTML;
        if (time === "8:00 p.m. - 8:00 p.m.")
            spans[i].innerHTML = "8:00 p.m.";
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you wrote something like this, you could actually NOT have to write out the actual time for each case -- just see if the first part of time string matches the second, and if so, use the first time string in your span:
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('span.eventTime').each(function () {
   var time = $(this).text().split('-');
   if (time[0].trimRight() === time[1].trim())
    $(this).text("changed");
  });
 });
</script>`